# Magento Code Migration Toolkit: [WARNING]: 0 modules were converted

Tags: magento, github, cmd, code-migration

i'm using a code-migration-toolkit by Magento.

When i'm running the first step, `php bin/migrate.php migrateModuleStructure <src> <dst>`,
this is my output:

```
[2016-06-17 03:44:55][INFO]: Starting module structure converter

←[0;33m[2016-06-17 03:44:55][WARNING]: 0 modules were converted←[0m

[2016-06-17 03:44:55][INFO]: Ending module structure converter
```

i check the log `migration.log` , this is the output:

```
[2016-06-17 03:44:55][INFO]: Starting module structure converter

[2016-06-17 03:44:55][WARNING]: 0 modules were converted

[2016-06-17 03:44:55][INFO]: Ending module structure converter
```

Ref: https://github.com/magento/code-migration

Answer (score 0):

The output might might be caused by:

- Mistyped directories structure :  `php bin/migrate.php migrateModuleStructure magento1\sampleModule magento2\sampleModule`
- `app\code\community\Vendor\Module\etc\config.xml`
  should be existing in module1
- Are the directory permission set to 777

Comment: directory permission set to 777, how do i do this?

Comment: **Please search yourself before asking**. It depends what operating system you are using. Basically to create new files directory must have permission to write.

Comment: i have converted my module using another tool, (https://github.com/unirgy/convertm1m2) since i cannot get this tool work. So right now i'm working with the code. I will get back to this once my module is done upgrading to be used by Magento 2. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: In my mac all the migration scripts except convertPhpCode run as intended to. Are you sure `composer install` did not throw any errors

Comment: hi i have encounter a new problem, feel free to have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319940/magento-2-redirecting-to-payment-gateway-error